# Executing .jar file in PHP script as another user: Permission problems

Tags: php, linux

I need to write a php script, that executes a java program. The .jar file calls another .jar file and executes some commands on command line.

I use XAMPP on Ubuntu 14.04. All necessary files are in htdocs. This command works without flaws:

```
myusername@null:/opt/lampp/htdocs# java -jar program.jar arg1 arg2 arg3
```

First i tried to execute the above command in php that way:

```
echo shell_exec(java -jar program.jar arg1 arg2 arg3)
```

Unfortunately i get some errors, because folders cannot be created and the background commands cannot be performed by program.jar. The htdocs folder has drwxrwxrwx permissions. 
As php is executed by user *deamon*, I suggest that it simply does not have all necessary permissions.

Before changing the entire system, I would like to execute the command from user *myusername*.

```
echo shell_exec(sudo -u myusername java -jar program.jar arg1 arg2 arg3)
```

This slight modification just returns no output.

Bizarrely this command does not work as well (executing as root):

```
root@null:/opt/lampp/htdocs# sudo -u myusername java -jar program.jar arg1 arg2 arg3
```

**Questions:**

1. Why can't I run the last command, though the first one works. In my understanding they are equivalent.
2. What do I need to change that I can successfully run the third command?

Comment: sudo is going to prompt for a password, and you'd have to check if the daemon user actually HAS sudoers rights to do this.

Comment: I haven't tried "sudo -u myusername" but you're issue definitely is daemon not having enough rights to execute the program. What does the .jar/java program is doing? is it creating files or folders?

Comment: @Marc B: You are probably right. I could solve my problem by adding _daemon ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL_ to _/etc/sudoers_. Nevertheless I don't understand why the first and forth command are not equivalent.

Comment: because 1st attempt is running as `myusername`. You **HAVE** to provide a password to become some other user. If you didn't, then any user `x` on your system could simply `sudo -u y` and become user `y` without any confirmation. Your 4th attempt, you're running as root. Root is "god" and doesn't need anyone's permission to "become" someone else.